# Invalid credentials in laravel using jwt

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I have uploaded about this problem many more times and none worked for me, I tried my best but still not working. I am not sure where does it go wrong.I have installed tymon/jwt-auth from the documnetation and installed laravel service provide after publishing. Then I change the default guard as api and set one user guard and another one admin guard. Sets the providers , Here are the code:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin_api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'admin_apis',
            'hash' => false,
    ],        
    
    ],

 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admin_apis' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Then set this in jwt.php  `'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class,`

**Kernel.php**

```
 protected $middlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

**User Model:**

```
 <?php
// app/Models/User.php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'], 401);
        }

        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }

    public function me()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }
}
```

**Api.php**

```
<

?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminDataController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ManagerDataController;


// Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// });

// routes/api.php

Route::post('user/login', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'login']);
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/me', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'me']);
    Route::post('user/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'logout']);
});

Route::post('admin/login', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'login']);
Route::middleware('auth:admin_api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/me', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'me']);
    Route::post('admin/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'logout']);
});
```

It returns invalid credentials but the field data are exists. How can I solve this?

Comment: Take a look at the this package `config/auth.php`, `Kernel & Middleware` and `Controllers\Http\Auth` https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa

Comment: why are you using `tymon/jwt-auth` in the first place vs plain cookie auth?

Comment: Strange as you’re using jwtAuth from package but documentation says you have to use auth in controller.. https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/